# Alternate editor (emacs/vim) in Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle)

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am new to kettle (Pentaho Data Integration) and am trying to develop some custom Java/JavaScript code.

Is it possible to either edit the text blobs in emacs/aquamacs/vim/anything-else and/or save the scripts in separate files that can be directly edited in something else?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I do this all the time.

I simply cut/paste code to and from my text editor.

Testing the code is a bit of a problem, since the code needs to run in context of PDI to evaluate variables properly; however the process works fine for me.

Hope this helps...